# Stretch FrameLayout to visible screen

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

My interface looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zADUL.png

[image]

Is there any simple solution which helps me to stretch FrameLayout to visible screen? I tried to set fillViewport and wrap_content to tabcontent children, but it didn't help.

Comment: see the solution I have posted for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Form" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#cccccc" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="#ff0000" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#cccccc" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: it didn't help too. Interface looks this way: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/cFUD9ll) instead of [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/5Qe0xyt).

Comment: I found that the problem was in another part of the application, but your solution also works well. Thanks.